# How to scroll sweet alert box in Landscape view of phone

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sweetalert

How to scroll sweet alert box, I am using Sweet alert when it get open in landscape view in phone sweet alert box gets half hidden and I am unable to scroll it down, hence unable to click on buttons

Comment: Please go through - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and consider updating your question with the code you have tried till now, error scenario etc.